# How can I put the image glued to the right side of the screen with css?

Tags: css

How do I align the image with the right side of the screen so it covers the white area? I would like also to remove the vertical scroll. I Have tried to use float right and flex in css, but no luck.

How I want to it too look, but without the scrollings:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4Beb.jpg)

Problem image

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYpq4.jpg)

#### HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-PT">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>A'TECH - Home</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/common-css.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/home.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="brand-logo">️ A'TECH</div>
        <div class="navbar-links">
            <a href="../html/home.html">Home</a> <span>-</span>
            <a href="../html/work.html">CEO</a> <span>-</span>
            <a href="../html/work.html">Shop</a> <span>-</span>
            <a href="../html/about.html">About</a> <span>-</span>
            <a href="../html/work.html">A.I Chatbot</a> <span>-</span>
            <a href="../html/work.html">Social Media Manager</a>
        </div>
        <div class="auth-links">
            <a href="../html/work.html">CEO Free Tool (Register & Login)</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="sections">
        <div class="carousel-section">
            <div class="carousel">
                <h1 class="carousel-header">A.I CHATBOT</h1>
                <p class="carousel-description">
                    Chat Bot (inteligência artificial - IA). Um chatbot é um programa de computador que simula conversas humanas por meio de mensagens de texto ou voz. Já a IA é um campo da ciência da computação que se concentra em criar máquinas capazes de realizar tarefas que normalmente exigiriam inteligência humana.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-image">
            <img class="ocean-view-image" src="/public/images/ocean-view.jpg" alt="Ocean View">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)

@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Then add additional custom code here

.sections {
  width:50%;

  color: white;

  display: flex;

  justify-content: start;
}

.carousel-section {
    margin-top: 30%;
    margin-left: 30%;

  position: ab;
}

.carousel-section > h1 {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.auth-links {
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.brand-logo {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.ocean-view-image {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 110vh;
}
```

I tried to use float right.

Comment: Can you [crop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)) the images, please? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written today). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this:

```html
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between;"> <!--main div--> <!--inside you have two children div's. and you are making them flex that's it-->

<div> Child one (whatever the text you have on the left side)</div> 
<div style="height:"100%"; width:"100%" overflow:hidden">Add your image here</div>

</div>
```